# Joomla user authentication from iOS/Android app - any feedback?

Tags: authentication

Not so much a question as a review request.
I am currently working on an app which needs to authenticate a user against an existing Joomla database which I have access to. As the password field in the database holds an encrypted password (and I can find no ready-to-go solution), I set about creating my own…

Although my need is related to an iOS app which I am developing, I believe that it is a workable solution for general use

Looking at the hashed passwords, I realised that they were in Blowfish format so that - knowing the password - I should be able to extract the salt then use it to hash the user's password before attempting to authenticate.

The code assumes a working knowledge of Joomla / MySQL / PHP / JSON queries

```
<?php 
require("conf.php");
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);
// if there is some error connecting to the database
// with die we will stop the further execution by displaying a message causing the error 
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Check that it is a POST request.
if(strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], 'POST') != 0){
    throw new Exception('Request method must be POST!');
}

// Check that the content type of the POST request has been set to application/json
$contentType = isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) ? trim($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) : '';
if(strcasecmp($contentType, 'application/json') != 0){
    throw new Exception('Content type must be: application/json');
}

// Receive the RAW post data.
$content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));
// ttempt to decode the incoming RAW post data from JSON.
$decoded = json_decode($content, true);
// If json_decode failed, the JSON is invalid.
if(!is_array($decoded)){
    throw new Exception('Received content contained invalid JSON!');
}

// Get username and password from POST data
$username = $decoded["username"];
$pass = $decoded["password"];

//creating an array for storing the data 
$userDetails = array(); 

// Get stored password field from db and store in variable
$sql = "SELECT password FROM ".$dbprefix."users WHERE username = '$username'";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$encryptedStr = $row['password'];
    
// Process password from DB extracting salt and hash value
$bits = array();
$salt = substr($encryptedStr, 7, 22);
$hash = substr($encryptedStr, 29);
$crypted = crypt($pass, "$2y$10$".$salt);

// Add to JSON for information - not necessary for live site
array_push($bits, "From DB: ".$encryptedStr); 
array_push($bits, "Crypted: ".$crypted); 
array_push($bits, "Salt: ".$salt); 
array_push($bits, "Hash: ".$hash); 

array_push($userDetails, $bits);

// SQL statement using password in same format as DB - in the example, 
// using the id field - however any other field will do
$sql = "SELECT id FROM ".$dbprefix."users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$crypted'";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$id = $row['id'];

// Add user id to JSON
array_push($userDetails, $id);

// Return JSON from server
echo json_encode($userDetails);
```

Comment: For the eyeballs of Joomla subject matter experts (SMEs), try [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  For code reviews, you are bound to receive better feedback on [codereview.se] versus Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks @mickmackusa  - that's very helpful. Can you advise if there is a way of moving the thread to the JSE which will be preferable to duplication?

Comment: Please join JSE, then I'll contact Stack Overflow mods to migrate this page to JSE.

Comment: Why does this script look like it ia running outside of Joomla's core structure? You aren't using Joomla's db connection, you are incorrectly implementing prepared statements because you aren't binding variables to placeholders, and I only call `array_push()` when pushing multiple elements at once.

Comment: Thanks, again, for the comments @mickmackusa
You're quite correct in that I'm running outside of Joomla core as the purpose of the script is to enable an iOS/Android app to connect to a Joomla database directly. Background is that I have a Joomla website which is quite a large system and I need to authenticate users against it within an iOS app. Hope that makes sense. I'll take on board your comments re: prepared statements/array_push and make changes as necessary

Comment: And have now joined JSE

Comment: Welcome here! Is this for Joomla 3 or 4?

Comment: AFAIK - User password hashing is same for both J3 and J4 - so, as it bypasses the J structure, should be workable for both.

Comment: I am asking this, not because of hashing, but because in Joomla 4 you should use joomla web services API for this kind of jobs… You can simply authenticate, create, delete, update users without the hashing and other hustles.

Comment: https://docs.joomla.org/Joomla_Api_Specification

Comment: Your code looks good though, I just wanted to give you another approach for Joomla 4.